# csv reader breaks rows incorrectly

Tags: python, csv

I'm fetching a csv via ssh for processing.

```
import csv
logging.info(csv_content)
for row in csv.reader(csv_content):
  logging.info(row)  # expecting [date, name, count]
```

The logged rows have been split into six lesser once. Unlike every other time I've done this.

```
"2018-01-01 01","NAME1","1"
"2018-01-01 01","NAME2","55"
"2018-01-01 02","NAME1","2"
...

['2018-01-01 01']
['', '']
['NAME1']
['', '']
['1']
[]
['2018-01-01 01']
['', '']
['NAME2']
['', '']
['55']
[]
...
```

It must be the file, somehow. I've played around with encoding and csv-parameters but it has me stomped.

I can't be the first encountering this?

Comment: Can you get the raw file? This looks like an issue of separator mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader don't want the csv_content. it want the csv-file. this in order to read each line.

Solution is to split lines prior to feeding reader.

```
for row in csv.reader(csv_content.split("\n")):
```